# An ugly function finding the maximum std::set element less than a given key

Tags: c++

When I write a code that is a bit strange I have a feeling that I probably misunderstand something.
Is there a better implementation of `find_less` function than provided below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using Set = std::set<int>;

Set set{ 0, 1, 3, 7, 9, 10 };

Set::iterator find_less(int val)
{
    auto i = set.lower_bound(val);

    if (i == set.begin())
    {
        return set.end();
    }

    return --i;
}

int main()
{
    auto i = find_less(5);

    if (i != set.end())
    {
        //outputs 3
        std::cout << *find_less(5) << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Isn't it a bit strange that `std::set` has `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` functions that find the first element that is greater than (or equal to) a given key, but it does not have functions that find an element that is less (or equal to) a given key?

**EDIT1:**

There is

```
std::lower_bound(set.rbegin(), set.rend(), val)
```

But looks like it is logarithmic only with random access iterators, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound :  *std::set and std::multiset iterators are not random access, and so their member functions std::set::lower_bound (resp. std::multiset::lower_bound) should be preferred.*

Comment: You're checking if `lower_bound` returns `set.end()`, but you should probably be checking if it returns `set.begin()`.  `*find_less(11)` will cause Undefined Behavior, as will `*find_less(0)`.

Comment: @DrewDormann updated the post.

Comment: Now that you've changed the code in your question, `*find_less(11)` will _still_ cause Undefined Behavior.  It will dereference the _end iterator_.  And `find_less(0)` will now return an iterator that is **not** less than the given key.

Comment: i am confused by less than, equal, first, maximum, ... what is the expected output? 3 ? what is expected result for `find_less(7)` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `find_less(5)` returns `3`, note that there is no element `5` in the set.

Comment: These comments may lead to an answer to your second "Isn't it strange..." question.  Containers in C++ support a "one past the end" iterator, but not a "one before the beginning" iterator.

Comment: @DrewDormann yes, it is a good idea, but they have reverse iterators.

Comment: @DrewDormann probably `find_less` should return a reverse iterator, because returning `set.end()` with `val == 0` makes it even more ugly.

Comment: ugly is purely subjective. Why do you think it is ugly? Isnt it doing what you want it to do? Similar "better", what do you consider as better?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I would consider a better `std::lower_bound` with a reverse iterator for example.

Comment: You need the member function `std::set::lower_bound` not the free function `std::lower_bound`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution that accounts for all potential inputs may be one that returns `end()` to **exclusively** mean

> *No element in the set meets the criteria*

```
auto find_less(const Set& set, int val)
{
    auto i = set.lower_bound(val);
    return (i == set.begin()) ? set.end() : std::prev(i);
}
```

I have also changed your function signature to allow a set to be provided, instead of always searching one particular global variable.

Comment: Yes it is a bit better

Answer (score 1):

Basically, upper_bound and lower_bound are both *forward* algorithms -- they start at the beginning (lowest element) of a collection and go until they find an element that meets a criterion (>= a value or > a value), returning an iterator to the found element (or end).  So they inherently find the first element that meets a predicate.  If you want to find the *last* element that meets a predicate, you need a reverse search, but maps and sets do not provide that.

Your code is a bit more complex than it needs to be -- you don't need to compare against set.end(), just set.begin();

---

If you're really bugged by having to write a helper function that "backs up" one, you can use a set with std::greater as the comparator instead:

```
using Set = std::set<int, std::greater<int>>;
```

and then just use `lower_bound` (or `upper_bound`) directly.

Comment: Corrected the code.  Why maps and sets do not provide them? Why not to add `reverse_lower_bound` and `reverse_uppder_bound`?